# JavaFx: After dialog, two textfields gains focus instead one

Tags: javafx-2

following issue: 
The instruction in the changeListener leads to the behavior that two TextFields gets Focus after a Dialog.

When Postleitzahl loses focus it open a dialog. If you click OK, just first textfield have to gain the focus . But what really happen is that the textfield below gains focus too.

The method "controlMinChar" sets the minimum amount of numbers. The method setMinCharacter uses the method and uses the focusedProperty

```
  private void setMinCharacter(){

    plz.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean lostFocus, Boolean getFocus) {

            if(lostFocus){

                     generalControler.controlMinChar(plz, 5, 
                    (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow(), 
                    errorMessage);

            }

        }
    });


}
```

I hope you can help me. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Am I correct, that there is a situation, when two controls gain focus on the scene? That is easy - just file an issue on javafx, on controls, in http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa. Create issue -> runtime/bug. Don't forget to provide a code (reproducible test case). But previously, check, that you have the latest accessible version of JavaFX.

Comment: Yes, after push OK in the Dialog. 

Here is a picture http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/focus1n9gipsb10z.png 

and here is a picture of the following behaviour: 
http://www.fotos-hochladen.net/view/focus2cd7ioyvr3g.png

(sorry, need 10 reputation to set pictures)

Comment: Which operation/method do you use, to move focus on the plz (that is - to move focus back)?

Comment: I've filed an issue : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28363

Answer (score 1):

Issue is : http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-28363

Workaround :

```
    tf1.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean lostFocus, Boolean getFocus) {
            if (lostFocus) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tf1.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, hope the issue will be correct soon. Meanwhile im so addicted for javafx and i have to convince my profesor to change his syllabus from swing to javafx but with this kind of issue it will be very difficult :) 

Anyway, thank you!

Comment: You can vote up that issue, to make it fixed sooner. (or vote up its dublicate, if it will be marked as dublicating some other issue)