# How to stop arrow keys navigating controls

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm trying to stop the arrow keys from navigating through the controls i have in my example. I'm not sure how to do this. Here is the example i have created:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class KeyEventTest extends Application{

    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyEventHandler;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Group root = new Group();
        FlowPane f = new FlowPane();
        Button r = new Button("button1");
        Button r2 = new Button("button1");
        Button r3 = new Button("button1");
        f.getChildren().addAll(r,r2,r3);
        root.getChildren().add(f);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
        keyEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT || keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    System.out.println("arrow keys");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(keyEvent);
                }
            }
        };
        stage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEventHandler);


        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem and found an easy workaround. Since the controls navigating Part triggers after the self-implemented EventHandler you can simply stop any further propagation of the KeyEvent by calling

```
    keyevent.consume()
```

at the end of your handle() method.

Answer (score -1):

First, the answer on this question is similar to answer on this question : [JavaFX: How to change the focus traversal policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238928/javafx-change-focus-traversal-policy)

You can change traversal policy, so that traverse will not be done, for some situations.

The other decision - is to add listener of focused property, and drop focus back, when it is not wished (but it will work for all navigation keys):

```
node.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>(){
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                        node.requestFocus();
                    }
                });                    
            }
        });
```

You should use runLater, because of such issue : [JavaFx: After dialog, two textfields gains focus instead one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841622/javafx-after-dialog-two-textfields-gains-focus-instead-one)

The way how you do this - handler on key press may not work always, because actions may happen on key release too.

In common case, behavior on key presses is determined in behavior class, which is accessible by skin class. If you want to change behavior on keys pressing, you can change behavior class.