# In JavaFX 2.2, is it possible to make a parent disabled, yet let his children remain not disabled?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, parent-child, disabled-control

This problem has hit me multiple times. For instance, I wanted a [`ProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressBar.html) graphical node in a [`Button`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) to be enabled, but have his parent Button disabled. That way, I could achieve a cool looking "loading" button that ran some long running task, becoming grayed out and disabled, but have his in-house ProgressBar remain clearly visible with all the bright colors attached. But when I disable the button, the precious child ProgressBar become disabled and grayed out too.

And today again I hit the same problem. I have two [`Accordions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Accordion.html) stacked sequentially after each other. The top Accordion features two [`TitledPanes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html), that the user can expand or contract at will. However, the Accordion below has only one TitledPane that is always expanded. This TitledPane features content and controls always visible to the user. I wrapped all of this fixed content in an separate Accordion and a separate TitledPane so that he could melt in with the same look and feel as his cousins. Just putting in a regular [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) or something, then trying to mimic the cousins styles was a real hassle. Please have a look at how everything currently looks:

[image]

But it looks darn ugly when the fixed content's TitlePane gets focus. The title "Send" lights up like a clear blue sky. So I tried to disable that TitlePane completely, but as one can imagine, the Button too automatically becomes disabled:

[image]

However, as with my first Button-example and the ProgressBar, I simply put it want to disable the Parent, yet keep the Child **not** disabled! Is it possible?

*Alternatively*, I could just hide the title of the TitledPane. But I haven't figured out how to do that either and asked the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17513541/1268003).

Answer (score 1):

Until I have a real solution (disable the parent and not the child), I've found a work around. Simply make the titled pane forward his focus to the button!

Given that the lower TitledPane with his title "Send" has a fx:id of "titledPaneSend", and that the Button have a fx:id "button", and that the controller class implements [`Initializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html), add this code to the initialize method:

```
titledPaneSend.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean from, Boolean to)
            {
                if (to == true)
                    /*
                     * Just calling button.requestFocus() will make
                     * BOTH the TitledPane and the Button become
                     * focused. And apparently, this is a bug:
                     * 
                     *     http://stackoverflow.com/a/14843531/1268003
                     * 
                     * So the fix is to wrap all in a new runnable:
                     */
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
                        {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            button.requestFocus(); }
                        });
            }
        });
```