# Hide the title of a TitledPane in JavaFX 2.2

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, accordion, visibility, titlebar

A [`TitledPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html) features a title. Here is how a couple of them can look:

[image]

The titles are "More..", "Smileys" and "Send". I want to completely hide the Send title, not just remove the text "Send". The end result should be something like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you clarify : "I want to completely hide the Send title, not just remove the text." which "text" do you mean?

Comment: I did. Does it makes sense now? You see I can remove the arrow, as I already did. And if I nullify the title's text, the text will be removed too. But the title itself will linger on. So, I want to remove it completely and only be left with a content pane that is styled the way the Accordions TitledPane are.

Comment: lol I even clarified the question even more with another picture.

Comment: May be... try to use Node.lookupAll() method to find all nodes, which are titles of TitlePanes, and set to the Title-node "Send" maxHeight to be 0? And set focusTraversable to be false

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, using the null argument, the empty string, finally strings like ".title" et cetera but I cannot get hold of any child elements of neither the Accordion nor the TitledPane.

Comment: Alexander, are you saying that it is possible and that I must have used wrong strings to the lookup and lookupAll methods? Otherwise I do think your approach is completely right. If only I could get hold of the title child node.

Comment: That is really strange, that you cannot find nodes via lookupAll(".title"), because (a) it looks right, (b) .title selector is used in modena/caspian css files. If you cannot make it work, you can use getChildrenUnmodifiable() method and recursive search.

Comment: Yes I've tried that too! And I get back a completely empty list! Size == 0. That goes for both the Accordion and the TitledPane :'(

Comment: removing the title of a *TitledPane* is like removing the list of a ListView. Why would you want to do that? Why don't you just use another pane that is untitled, like StackPane?

Comment: What is the desired behaviour? Do you want the bottom pane to collapse when the 'Smileys' header is collapsed or do you want it to still be visible?

Comment: Valid questions indeed =) I want the desired look that the second picture portrays. I do not want any particular behavior. All I want is the same style applied to my pane that all the rest TitlePanes enjoy, but without a title bar. The lower pane with the button, is supposed to be fixed - not collapsible, animated or anything else. Just a regular pane with the same style!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a standard `Pane` for the third content area rather than a `TitledPane` and apply the relevant styles to trick JavaFX into styling the bottom panel as if it was the content area of a `TitlePane`.

Roughly speaking you will require some FXML markup similar to this:

```
<VBox styleClass="titled-pane" 
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"  
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" >
    <children>
        <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" 
                            minWidth="0.0" 
                            prefHeight="180.0" 
                            prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
        </TitledPane>
        <TitledPane animated="false" text="untitled">
            <content>
                <AnchorPane id="Content" 
                            minHeight="0.0" 
                            minWidth="0.0" 
                            prefHeight="180.0" 
                            prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
        </TitledPane>
        <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" styleClass="content">
            <children>
                <Button layoutX="74.0" 
                        layoutY="21.0" 
                        mnemonicParsing="false" 
                        text="Button" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

This basically lays the three panes out in a VBox so that they stack correctly and applies some styles to tell JavaFX how to render the third `Pane`.

In order to achieve the correct look of the third `Pane` you will need to give it a style class of "content". This is the name of the background `Pane` that is part of the `TitledPanes` sub-structure and tells JavaFX to render the pane in the same way as the `TitledPane` control.

This will not work as it stands though as the actual css definition looks something like this:

```
.titled-pane .content { // styles defined here }
```

What this means is that the style will only apply to nodes that have a style class of "content" if they are also inside a node with a style class of "titled-pane".

The simple way to fix this is to give the root container `Pane` (the `VBox` in this case) a style class of "titled-pane", effectively tricking JavaFX into thinking the third pane is a `titledPanes` content area.

The output of this is shown below:

[image]

and with both `TitledPanes` collapsed:

[image]

Comment: wow, your answer was exactly what I needed. I see you have succeeded in making the lower pane grow upwards if both two upper title panes are collapsed. For me that doesn't happen. And yet my elements too are wrapped in a VBox. My VBox in turn is the second child of a HBox. There are even more things up the tree, but things I cannot change nor think have/should have anything to say about why my application behavior differs from yours. So, when I collapse my two title panes, there is white space in between and my lower pane won't go anywhere. Do you have an idea why that might be?

Comment: To be a bit more precise, my lower pane refuse to grow or expand beyond exactly 50 % of the total height of the VBox. The pane, so to speak, stay in the lower half. Imagine that it would be just like if your white space in the lower picture in your answer was put in between the second untitled title and the "hacked" pane instead of being at the bottom of the window as it is now.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing your actual layout. I've tried my example nested within a a HBox and I agree it does mess up the layout. I have played around with the preferred / max size values and the VGrow property of the three containers and the VBox to fix it but you will need to experiment to get it working for your exact scenario.

Comment: I kind of fixed the problem through binding the preferred height of my lower pane to all the height being available. However, the accordion wanted a preferred height that was equal to exactly three titles so there was still space left over. I consider this a bug and redesigned my application to use three titles to begin with. Anyways, thank you for everything!

Comment: +1 This 7 year old answer fixed my issue in hiding a complete TitledPane as the usual managed/visible solution seems not to work. Additionally this enabled opening multiple panes.